# WPF Popup not automatically closing when raised from a ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, popup, listboxitem

I have a User Control with an image in it and when the user clicks the image I use a popup to display a record card. I set `StaysOpen="False"` and all works perfectly through my application, except when I host it in a ListBox. In this case the Popup refuses to recognise a click away from it. Is there an issue with raising a popup from a ListBoxItem or are there other ways around this?

Comment: You should show how you have implemented your logic. This way somebody else who has never seen your code can review it to tell you your mistake. Crystal balls are quite expensive these days, so I doubt many people here got one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, opening Popup using Interactivity commands instead of using a Button could be the issue.

Interactivity is not doing the mouse capture and keyboard focus actions. So, Popup will not have a proper mouse capture reference by using Interactivity commands.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer in the end and t was my mistake. The action to raise the popup was done on Mouse Down and the popup was opening and then closing on the mouse up cation. All I did was to change it to Mouse Up and it was fine. Thank you for your answer anyway.